# How do you split a text file using the split method in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to split a text file that I used NodeJS FS to read. When I try, it returns an array that includes encoded information.

I already tried decoding the array, but it didn't return anything.

Code:

```
const fs = require("fs"); 
var data = fs.readFileSync("data.txt", 'utf-8'); 
var dataArr = data.split('s');  
console.log(dataArr);
```

Output:

```
[ '��t\u0000e\u0000', '\u0000t\u0000' ]
[ '��t\u0000e\u0000', '\u0000t\u0000' ]
```

Text File:

```
test
```

I want it to return:

```
["te", "t"]
```

Comment: works fine here, check the contents of `data.txt`

Comment: you need to convert the stream data to characters: `var dataArr = data.toString().split('s');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) website `fs.readFileSync` return either `Buffer` or a `String`. The best way to do this would be to use `fs.readFileSync` without the `uft-8` option then change the buffer to `uft-8` using `toString('utf8')`

Example from your code

```
const fs = require("fs"); 
var data = fs.readFileSync("data.txt"); 
var dataArr = data.toString('utf8').split('s');  
console.log(dataArr);
```

Comment: `If the encoding option is specified then this function returns a string` and OP has done so

Comment: For me, this still outputs
```[ '��t\u0000e\u0000', '\u0000t\u0000' ]```
When I do ```var dataArr = data.toString('utf8')```, it outputs ```��t e s t```

Comment: @SASSY_ROG This technically answers the problem because it converts it to string, but I want it to translate to 'test' when decoded, like in the text file.